# Pandas - datetime format of milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a list of time strings saved in pandas in this format:

```
2743    2015-11-30-20-24-0-970
2744    2015-11-30-20-24-0-989
2745      2015-11-30-20-24-1-7
2746     2015-11-30-20-24-1-28
```

I need to transform it into datetime format, but when I do it like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(something['Date'],format="%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")
```

I get data in this format:

```
2743   2015-11-30 20:24:00.970
2744   2015-11-30 20:24:00.989
2745   2015-11-30 20:24:01.700
2746   2015-11-30 20:24:01.280
```

But the two last have wrong time format. It should be like:

```
2745   2015-11-30 20:24:01.007
2746   2015-11-30 20:24:01.028
```

Do you know which parameter should I use for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the vectorised [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html#pandas.Series.str.zfill) on the last element to pad with zeroes, you can get the correct result:

```
In [52]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""2743    2015-11-30-20-24-0-970
2744    2015-11-30-20-24-0-989
2745      2015-11-30-20-24-1-7
2746     2015-11-30-20-24-1-28"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names=['id', 'date'])
df

Out[52]:
     id                    date
0  2743  2015-11-30-20-24-0-970
1  2744  2015-11-30-20-24-0-989
2  2745    2015-11-30-20-24-1-7
3  2746   2015-11-30-20-24-1-28

In [53]:
df['date'] = df['date'].str.rsplit('-',n=1).str[0] + '-' + df['date'].str.rsplit('-',n=1).str[-1].str.zfill(3)
df

Out[53]:
     id                    date
0  2743  2015-11-30-20-24-0-970
1  2744  2015-11-30-20-24-0-989
2  2745  2015-11-30-20-24-1-007
3  2746  2015-11-30-20-24-1-028

In [54]:    
pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format="%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")

Out[54]:
0   2015-11-30 20:24:00.970
1   2015-11-30 20:24:00.989
2   2015-11-30 20:24:01.007
3   2015-11-30 20:24:01.028
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So the key thing is this line:

```
df['date'].str.rsplit('-',n=1).str[0] + '-' + df['date'].str.rsplit('-',n=1).str[-1].str.zfill(3)
```

This calls [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html#pandas.Series.str.rsplit) and takes the last element and then calls `zfill` on these, we then join it back with the rest of the string to get back what we want.

```
In [57]:
df['date'].str.rsplit('-',n=1).str[-1].str.zfill(3)

Out[57]:
0    970
1    989
2    007
3    028
dtype: object

In [58]:
df['date'].str.rsplit('-',n=1).str[0] + '-' + df['date'].str.rsplit('-',n=1).str[-1].str.zfill(3)

Out[58]:
0    2015-11-30-20-24-0-970
1    2015-11-30-20-24-0-989
2    2015-11-30-20-24-1-007
3    2015-11-30-20-24-1-028
dtype: object
```

Comment: I got this data from Android sensor. Do you thing it is possible to get them in 007 format than just 7?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest, it's something you'll need to check in the sdk